# How can I get Spark SQL to import a Long without an "L" suffix?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, long-integer, apache-spark-sql

I have a set of CSV's that I produced by Sqoop'ing a mySQL database.  I am trying to define them the source for a dataframe in Spark.

The schema in the source db contains several fields with a Long datatype, and actually stores giant numbers in those fields.

When trying to access the dataframe, Scala chokes on interpreting these because I do not have an L suffix on the long integers.

As an example, this throws an error: `val test: Long = 20130102180600`

While this succeeds: `val test: Long = 20130102180600L`

Is there any way to force Scala to interpret these as Long Integers without that suffix?  Due to the scale of the data, I do not believe it is feasible to post-process the fields as they come out of the database.

Comment: I've changed the title because "Scala" isn't importing anything here, it's a specific library.

Answer (score 1):

Give the schema explicitly, as in the example in README:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType}

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("year", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("make", StringType, true),
    StructField("model", StringType, true),
    StructField("comment", StringType, true),
    StructField("blank", StringType, true)))

val df = sqlContext.load(
    "com.databricks.spark.csv",
    schema = customSchema,
    Map("path" -> "cars.csv", "header" -> "true"))

val selectedData = df.select("year", "model")
selectedData.save("newcars.csv", "com.databricks.spark.csv")
```

Except using `LongType` for the large integer fields, of course.

Looking at the code, this definitely looks like it should work: fields are [converted from `String` to desired type using `TypeCast.castTo`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/CsvRelation.scala#L120), and `TypeCast.castTo` for `LongType` [just calls `datum.toLong`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/0c2551a0b38d006ff234442e6b655b2492023a0e/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/util/TypeCast.scala#L62) which works as desired (you can check `"20130102180600".toLong` in Scala REPL). In fact, `InferSchema` handles this case as well. I strongly suspect that the issue is different: perhaps the numbers are even out of `Long` range?

Comment: Ya, that is exactly what we are doing, I abbreviated for simplicity.  Do you think it is a bug with Scala, or with the databricks CSV library?

Comment: In the CSV library, of course. It _could_ be caused by a bug in Scala, but there is no reason to assume it is.